# Splitting row into multiple rows -- alternative to union?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I know it can be done with union, but is kind of repetitive -- so is there a way to split multi column every row into multiple single column rows?

Example:

```
SPLIT(SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM tbl);
```

SPLIT is my imaginary function, for:

```
SELECT col1 FROM tbl
UNION
SELECT col2 FROM tbl
UNION
SELECT col3 FROM tbl;
```

So, is there such UNION/SPLIT equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use `union all` -- unless you intend to incur the overhead to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT col1 FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT col2 FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT col3 FROM tbl;
```

The above requires scanning the table 3 times.  You can scan the table just once using `CROSS JOIN`, but the logic is a little more cumbersome:

```
SELECT (CASE col WHEN 1 THEN col1 WHEN 2 THEN col2 WHEN 3 THEN col3 END) as col
FROM tbl CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as col UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) x;
```

I should note that other databases support `unpivot` and lateral joins, either of which can be used for this purpose.  However, these constructs are not in MySQL.

Comment: Great, I don't want to use "union all" everywhere (it depends on the context), because sometimes I need all the values (the count has to match), but I wanted to avoid multiple query. So thank you very much for your help!